# kinect sdk 2.0 joint angles and tracking

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, kinect

How  to check whether the joints you are accessing have a tracking state of Tracked. I am finding the angles of 8 of the joints and I can't seem to get the result to be displayed on my screen,

```
public double AngleBetweenTwoVectors(Vector3D vectorA, Vector3D vectorB)
    {
        double dotProduct = 0.0;
        vectorA.Normalize();
        vectorB.Normalize();


        dotProduct = Vector3D.DotProduct(vectorA, vectorB);

        return (double)Math.Acos(dotProduct) / Math.PI * 180;
    }

    public double[] GetVector(Body skeleton)
    {

        Vector3D Shoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.SpineShoulder].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.SpineShoulder].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.SpineShoulder].Position.Z);
        Vector3D RShoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderRight].Position.Z);
        Vector3D LShoulder = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D RElbow = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Z);
        Vector3D LElbow = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D RWrist = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristRight].Position.Z);
        Vector3D LWrist = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.WristLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D RKnee = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeRight].Position.Z);
        Vector3D LKnee = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D RAnkle = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.AnkleRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.AnkleRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.AnkleRight].Position.Z);
        Vector3D LAnkle = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.AnkleLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.AnkleLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.AnkleLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D Hip = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.SpineBase].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.SpineBase].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.SpineBase].Position.Z);
        Vector3D RHip = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipRight].Position.Z);
        Vector3D LHip = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position.Z);


        double AngleRElbow = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(RElbow - RShoulder, RElbow - RWrist);
        double AngleRShoulder = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(RShoulder - Shoulder, RShoulder - RElbow);
        double AngleLElbow = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(LElbow - LShoulder, LElbow - LWrist);
        double AngleLShoulder = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(LShoulder - Shoulder, LShoulder - LElbow);
        double AngleRKnee = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(RKnee - RHip, RKnee - RAnkle);
        double AngleLKnee = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(LKnee - LHip, LKnee - LAnkle);
        double AngleRHip = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(RHip - Hip, RHip - RKnee);
        double AngleLHip = AngleBetweenTwoVectors(LHip - Hip, LHip - LKnee);


        Results.Add(AngleLShoulder);
        Results.Add(AngleLElbow);
        Results.Add(AngleLKnee);
        Results.Add(AngleLHip);
        Results.Add(AngleRShoulder);
        Results.Add(AngleRElbow);
        Results.Add(AngleRKnee);
        Results.Add(AngleRHip);

        double[] resultsArray = Results.ToArray();

        return resultsArray;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        result1.Text = Results[4].ToString();
        result2.Text = Results[5].ToString();
        result3.Text = Results[6].ToString();
        result4.Text = Results[7].ToString();
        result5.Text = Results[0].ToString();
        result6.Text = Results[1].ToString();
        result7.Text = Results[2].ToString();
        result8.Text = Results[3].ToString();
    }
```

There is live feed coming from the kinect to the program, but when the button is pressed, there is a null pointer exception thrown for some reason. I am thinking it is because i am not sure if the joints are tracked. How do I go about doing that?

Also is my code to display the angles correct? I am using textbox for each result.

Comment: which line gives the null pointer. Would be great if we have the stacktrace too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
            {
                if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
                {
                    //Do something                    
                }
                else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
                {
                    //Do something else                   
                }
            }
```

This loops through the Joints array and checks for every Joint if the `JointTrackingState` is `Tracked`, `Inferred` or `NotTracked`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.jointtrackingstate.aspx). The program to calculate the angles is perfectly fine.

If you have more questions on how to calculate the angle of Joints see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154420/finding-elbow-angle-with-kinect/27677705#27677705)**.

If you want a working programm, I'll send it to you per e-mail. Or see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061287/display-the-angles-of-each-joint-of-the-skeleton-in-kinect-c-sharp/27678086#27678086)**. Hope this helps :)